# Multi-threaded Cap'n Proto Python (pycapnp) RPC server

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, capnproto

I'm writing a simple RPC server in Python 3 using `pycapnp`. I have a single function call that takes roughly a second to complete. This function also needs data stored in a cache (currently implemented using `lru-dict`).

Everything works fine with a single client, but as soon as I start increasing the load, requests start queuing (wall time measured inside the function running on the server is ~1 second; on the client I can easily get 10 or more seconds).

As far as I can tell, there's currently no support in `pycapnp` for other event loops.

I've tried creating a `ThreadPoolExecutor` in the `__init__` method of the server implementation (where the cache is also created), and then adding the following to the RPC method:

```
capnp.Promise(self.executor.submit(long_running_function, request, cached_data).result()).\
        then(lambda result: setattr(_context.results, 'response', result))
```

While this works, the main thread is apparently still waiting on each `Promise` to be fulfilled, which again means clients have to queue.

Anyone in a similar situation found a way out? I don't *necessarily* have to use `pycapnp`, but that's the recommended Cap'n Proto Python implementation AFAICT.

Would serialising and then simply sending over a socket be simpler? I don't have use for promise pipelining or any other fancy features in Cap'n Proto RPC.

Comment: In a similar situation, we've found that serializing over a socket does work well.  So since we've never used the event loop I don't have enough information to give you an answer.